# Laravel filter using conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-filters

I have a eloquent model called `product`. I need to use where condition depends on the status of column in same table. This is my code

```
public function product_list(Request $request,Datatables $datatables){

    $product = Product::where('supplier_id',$request->supplier_id)->where('product','!=',3);

    return $datatables->eloquent($product)->filter(function ($query) use ($request) {
                    if($query->is_from_portalsite==1){
                        $query->where('status','>',1);
                     }
    })->make(true);

}
```

I need to check the where condition  if the column `is_from_portalsite` equals to 1. how can I check that in laravel.

Comment: ```$query->is_from_portalsite==1```
should be ```$request->is_from_portalsite==1``` if I understand your code correctly

Comment: no , not like that. I have column in table `is_from_portalsite` if the value of that column is `1` then i need to check the where condition.

Comment: what happens if its not 1 ?

Comment: if it is not 1 no need to check that where condition

Comment: why dont you write 2 return statements ?

Comment: it is a big query around 10 filter  are the i just shorten to post here. Can't we use `case when` in filter.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming `is_from_portalsite` is boolean):

```
$query->where('is_from_portalsite',0)->orWhere('status','>',1);
```

Comment: is_from_portalsite is boolean.But this is not i want. I need use `case when` in filter

Comment: Do you mean like this? `$query->whereRaw('CASE WHEN is_from_portalsite=1 THEN status>1 ELSE TRUE END')`

Comment: Yes something like that.Let me try that one